# Covariance matrix of fit parameters with SciPy

Tags: python, scipy

The distributions available in the `scipy.stats` module have `fit` methods (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) to estimate the parameters of a distribution given input data. Is there a way to get the covariance matrix of the fit parameters, or do I have to resort to using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`?

Comment: Haven't looked at the code but my guess is that `distrib.fit` is probably a wrapper around `curve_fit` anyway.

Comment: I don't think that is the case here. `curve_fit` uses the Marquardt-Levenberg algorithm (non-linear least-squares) for fitting. The `distrib.fit` methods use Maximum-Likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

The covariance of the parameter estimates needs the Hessian for the Maximum Likelihood estimation which is not available in scipy.stats.

statsmodels has a generic Maximum Likelihood class, that I'm just fixing so it can handle cases like this. (I'm in the middle of preparing a pull request. Fixed parameters are more difficult to handle than in scipy.stats.distribution.)

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/generated/example_gmle.html

```
mod_par = MyPareto(data)
res = mod_par.fit()
print res.summary()

                               MyPareto Results
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   Log-Likelihood:                -149.32
Model:                       MyPareto   AIC:                             306.6
Method:            Maximum Likelihood   BIC:                             317.1
Date:                Sat, 29 Jun 2013
Time:                        11:17:43
No. Observations:                 100
Df Residuals:                      97
Df Model:                           3
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
shape          2.8604      0.286     10.000      0.000         2.300     3.421
loc           -1.2970   4.48e-06   -2.9e+05      0.000        -1.297    -1.297
scale          3.3032   8.06e-06    4.1e+05      0.000         3.303     3.303
==============================================================================
```